# How to use the name of a file as a variable

Tags: python, variables, filenames, google-colaboratory

I want to be able to use the filename of a csv file that is loaded into google colab as a variable so that it can be used later on to make a somewhat automatic script.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Post an example of the usage you want, and your best coding effort to make that happen.

Comment: @YaNumpy could you explain more what you want with some examples and more details